# How to easily change a field from analyzed to non_analyzed

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat

I have a hostname field that's coming in via filebeat to my logstash instance is getting passed to ElasticSearch where it's being treated as an analyzed field.   That's causing issues, because the field itself needs to be reported on in it's totality.

Example:  Knowing how many requests come to "prd-awshst-x-01" rather than splitting those out into prd, awshst, x, 01.

Does anyone have a lightweight way of doing this that can be used with visualizations?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

We have to update mapping from analyzed to not_analyzed for specific field.

```
PUT/ mapping url/
{
   property:{
           field:{
               text:"not_analyzed"
                }
           }
}
```

After updating the property please check is it reflected in mapping using GET method on mapping url.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the title of your post, you already know that you need to change the mapping of the field to not_analyzed.

You should setup a template so that future indexes contain this mapping.

If you want to keep the existing data, you'll have to reindex it into a new index with the new mapping.

If you're using the default logstash template, it might be creating you a not_analyzed ".raw" field that you can use in visualizations in kibana.

Comment: How would I do what you mentioned in your last line there?  I've not had to make a non-analyzed field before and it seems to be pretty complex.

Comment: IIRC, Kibana doesn't show the .raw fields on the Discover tab, but will show them when building visualizations.  You can also curl the index's mapping from elasticsearch and see if they're there.

Answer (score 0):

The [index template](https://github.com/elastic/beats/blob/5.0/filebeat/filebeat.template-es2x.json#L28-L34) that is provided with Filebeat configures the hostname field as not_analyzed.

You should manually [install the index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-template.html#load-template-manually) provided with Filebeat and then configure Logstash to write data to the Filebeat index as described in the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/libbeat/5.0/logstash-installation.html#logstash-setup).

This is what the `elasticsearch` output would look like. If you are processing other data through Logstash, then you might want to add a conditional around this output so that only beat events are sent via this output.

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
    manage_template => false
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
  }
}
```